# Ubuntu 23.04/gnome-shell 44.1 wayland how to force use nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, gnome, wayland, 23.04

I have a laptop with nvidia RTX 3050 GPU and just installed Ubuntu 23.04, gnome 44.1 and wayland.
I tried nvidia driver 530, 535 but gnome-shell does not use nvidia driver on wayland session.
It uses intel UHD driver. So it's very slow on 4k monitor.

$ glxinfo | egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"

OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (TGL GT1)

When I turned into X11 session, nvidia works properly, and performs very well.

How can I force gnome-shell use nvidia propretary driver?

Comment: Open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T), type `nvidia-smi` and hit Enter. If that doesn't list your GPU, then you have a driver issue and need to rectify that. WinKey and typing `Addditional Drivers` should list Nvidia drivers (and allow to select one), if it doesn't look in the `Ubuntu Software`-tab and make sure all is selected except `Sources`, the go back check. Any earlier / remnants of drivers (installation attempts) must be removed / cleansed prior to this though.

Comment: `nvidia-smi` shows `NVIDIA-SMI 535.54.03              Driver Version: 535.54.03    CUDA Version: 12.2`

Answer (score 0):

For Wayland sessions you can control which GPU to use with an udev rule. Here's how to do it, assuming both of your drivers work correctly:

Create a new file with the nano text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/61-mutter-primary-gpu.rules
```

Paste the following content:

```
ENV{DEVNAME}=="/dev/dri/card1", TAG+="mutter-device-preferred-primary"
```

Save with CTRL + O, and press enter. Reboot your system.

Notice that in the example above I set it to card1, you probably have card0 and card1 in your system so you might have to try both to find the correct one. I have successfully used this method to change from my dedicated Nvidia GPU to my integrated AMD GPU when using Wayland (AMD drivers work better with Wayland).

Comment: thank you, but it does not work for me.